# Safely Drop User Table in Ruby on Rails Application

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm running a Ruby on Rails application. In this system, Users can login and logout as necessary. I used gem devise as well. I've realized now that I have a lot of Users in my system, but most of them are no longer users. I can delete them from the system, but I want to start afresh.

My question is, is it safe to drop the Users table, `User.delete_all`? Then insert myself using `seed.rb` as admin user. Then add all Users (new and old) from the system (Add New User feature I have on the system).

Comment: "drop the Users table" and `User.delete_all` are drastically different actions.

Answer (score 0):

What I believe you're looking for is the `delete_all`-action, if you have no callbacks etc in the `User`-model. Dropping the table, is *not* what you'll want, as you would have to rebuild and recreate the table. By deleting the rows in it, you're simply removing the content.

Depending on your use of Users, you could argue, that it's safe/unsafe to delete content. If the users are persisted, and you're storing password etc, you should not empty it.

If, on the other hand, a `User` is in fact a "session", or similar, you should be safe to empty it, as that would simply "log out" your users.

Another consideration is, if you need to cleanup the users, maybe add a field `last_logged_in` or similar. Leave it for a while (And of course update it, when a user logs in), and then delete anyone that hasn't logged in for, say 1 month; `User.where("last_logged_in < ?", 1.month.ago).delete_all`.

**I cannot recommend, just deleting content, without testing first, and ensuring that Users data are stored, or 'easily recoverable', by a new login. Or atleast that they're actually able to login without being baffled. Also, ensure that any relations from `User`, is handled, or you'll end up with orphaned records in other tables.**